# VB.Net Table Adapter (Visual Studio) - NULLReferenceException

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, nullreferenceexception, tableadapter

I'm a beginner when it comes to VB based languages and have never worked with Table Adapters.  I have a Data Source with the following tables.  Previously, I was using a different database and now switched to a different one.  The new one has the same tables except the values may or may not be different.  I'm getting a "NULLReferenceException was unhandeled".  I checked the Data Sources to make sure that table existed and it does...Could it be because the table adapter exists with the previous database (most of the tables have the same exact name in the new DB as the previous DB)? Any help will be appreciated!

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CEDOPT_Model_HCCDataSet.PriceJointSensitivity' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.PriceJointSensitivityTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CEDOPT_Model_HCCDataSet.PriceJointSensitivity)
    Me.Yield_Dist_ShapeTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CEDOPT_Model_HCCDataSet.Yield_Dist_Shape)
    Me.PriceSensitivityCurvesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CEDOPT_Model_HCCDataSet.PriceSensitivityCurves)
    Me.Factor_RevPlan_CalibrateTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CEDOPT_Model_HCCDataSet.Factor_RevPlan_Calibrate)
    Me.APH_RangesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CEDOPT_Model_HCCDataSet.APH_Ranges)
    Me.Temp_state_updateTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CEDOPT_Model_HCCDataSet.temp_state_update)
    Me.Ref_StateTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CEDOPT_Model_HCCDataSet.ref_State)
    Me.PriceCVTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CEDOPT_Model_HCCDataSet.PriceCV)
    Me.CV_to_LossTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CEDOPT_Model_HCCDataSet.CV_to_Loss)
    Me.Factor_PriceElection_HCCTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CEDOPT_Model_HCCDataSet.Factor_PriceElection_HCC)
    'Me.Factor_PracticeTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CEDOPT_Model_HCCDataSet.Factor_Practice)
    Me.Factor_InsPlan_HCCTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CEDOPT_Model_HCCDataSet.Factor_InsPlan_HCC)
    Me.Factor_Crop_HCCTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CEDOPT_Model_HCCDataSet.Factor_Crop_HCC)
    Me.Factor_Coverage_HCCTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CEDOPT_Model_HCCDataSet.Factor_Coverage_HCC)
    Me.Factor_County_HCCTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CEDOPT_Model_HCCDataSet.Factor_County_HCC)
    Me.Factor_APHBand_HCCTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CEDOPT_Model_HCCDataSet.Factor_APHBand_HCC)
    Me.Factor_AcreBand_HCCTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CEDOPT_Model_HCCDataSet.Factor_AcreBand_HCC)
    Me.BadPIndexTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CEDOPT_Model_HCCDataSet.BadPIndex)
    'Added 3/3/2015 to accomodate for weather variable
    Me.Factor_DnSolTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CEDOPT_Model_HCCDataSet.Factor_LTDnSol)

End Sub
```

Comment: You should know that Vb.Net and VBA are two completely different languages.  You are using VB.NET, not VBA

Comment: @TimWilliams   I suppose I was being super general as I don't know all the languages.  All I work with are VBA and SQL. Fixed the naming conventions.  Thanks.

Comment: The error would indicate that the tables called in the .Fill method are not referencing anything.  You could probably step through to verify that.  We don't have any info on how they are defined, so it is hard to know what might be happening.

Comment: @Steve I added the tables to the Data Set and I see values there.  Where and how do I define them? Not taking into consideration the tables already there, if I wanted to add a new Table Adapter row with a different table name, what would I have to do to accommodate? If I try to add a brand new table, say table X, I get " 'XTableAdapter' is not a member of 'CropModel0._1.Form'"  How do I make it a "member"?

Comment: Was it working before you switched?

Comment: @Steve Yes but that's because I didn't have any new tables.  I looked into it and I need to define the TableAdapter in the form but I'm confused as to how I add a TableAdapter to a form...

Comment: Never mind everyone.  I figured it out how to add the code on the Form! Thanks for all the help!